# Displaying Value of setFieldErrors Using ErrorMessage Component in Formik

Tags: reactjs, formik

**See Update Below**

I have a Login Form Component that I built using Formik that syncs with Firebase Authentication.  I have set it up so that I can display errors from Firebase using the `setFieldError` prop.  Here is the relevant sections of the code:

```
export const LoginForm = () => {
  async function authenticateUser(values, setFieldError) {
    const { email, password } = values

    try {
      await firebase.login(email, password)
      navigate('/', { replace: true })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Authentication Error: ', error)
      await setFieldError('firebaseErrorMessage', error.message)
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Form</h1>
      <Formik
        render={props => <RenderForm {...props} />}
        initialValues={initialValues}
        validationSchema={validationSchema}
        onSubmit={async (
          values,
          { setFieldError, setSubmitting, resetForm }
        ) => {
          setSubmitting(true)
          authenticateUser(values, setFieldError)
          setSubmitting(false)
          resetForm()
        }}
      />
    </>
  )
}

const RenderForm = ({ errors, isSubmitting, isValid }) => (
  <Form>
    <h3>Sign Up</h3>
    <Email name="email" />
    <Password name="password" />
    <Button disabled={!isValid || isSubmitting} type="submit">
      Submit
    </Button>
    {errors.firebaseErrorMessage && <p>{errors.firebaseErrorMessage}</p>}
  </Form>
)
```

Now, this works just fine.  However, if I try to display the error message using Formik's `ErrorMessage` component, then the message does not show up.

In other words, this works:

```
{errors.firebaseErrorMessage && <p>{errors.firebaseErrorMessage}</p>}
```

This does **not** work:

```
<ErrorMessage name="firebaseErrorMessage" />
```

Any idea why this doesn't work and how to get it to work?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Here are my initial values:

```
const initialValues = {
  email: '',
  password: '',
}
```

Comment: Does it make a difference if you `await authenticateUser(values, setFieldError);` in your `onSubmit`? Also, can you include your `initialValues` object?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think that you should use Formik's error for your Firebase error. Formik's errors are meant for validating form inputs.

To store and reference an API error, you can use Formik's [`status`](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik#setstatus-status-any-void) object. Handling API errors is the example he gives for `status`.

I think the issue is that, in Formik, `name` is meant to refer to the name of an input. Instead, you're imperatively adding a new name property to the `errors` object using `setFieldError`, but `firebaseErrorMessage` isn't a field in your form. (Share your `initialValues` object to verify this.)

One annoying part of this is that there is probably some styling associated with `<ErrorMessage>` that you can't leverage directly. But, in my opinion, it's probably more important to have your system structured correctly, and then you can mimic styles as-needed.

Here's my code suggestion:

```js
const RenderForm = ({ isSubmitting, isValid, status }) => (
  <Form>
    <h3>Sign Up</h3>
    <Email name="email" />
    <Password name="password" />
    <Button disabled={!isValid || isSubmitting} type="submit">
      Submit
    </Button>
    {status.firebaseErrorMessage && <p>{status.firebaseErrorMessage}</p>}
  </Form>
);

export const LoginForm = () => {
  async function authenticateUser(values, setStatus, setSubmitting) {
    const { email, password } = values;

    setSubmitting(true);

    try {
      await firebase.login(email, password);
      navigate("/", { replace: true });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Authentication Error: ", error);
      setStatus({
        firebaseErrorMessage: error.message
      });
    } finally {
      setSubmitting(false);
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Form</h1>
      <Formik
        render={props => <RenderForm {...props} />}
        initialValues={initialValues}
        validationSchema={validationSchema}
        onSubmit={async (values, { setStatus, setSubmitting, resetForm }) => {
          await authenticateUser(values, setStatus, setSubmitting);
          resetForm();
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of why the `ErrorMessage` component won't work.  With that said, I'm not sure I understand the advantage of of `useState` over `setFieldError`.  Would you mind explaining why one is better than the other?  Thanks.

Comment: Formik's `errors` object holds errors which correspond to the `values` of the form. It's meant to say, "Your `email` field doesn't contain valid email syntax", or "Password can't contain symbols", that sort of thing. Formik is used to validate form data. Each form input might need to be validated differently.

Here, your concern is the API error. It's not directly related to the structure of the data input. I think it makes sense to create your own errors object for concerns unrelated to the form inputs' validity. It's an API error, not a form error.

Comment: I just remembered Formik's [status](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik#setstatus-status-any-void) object. Try that instead of state I think.

Comment: Thanks three times over -- for the answer, the explanation and the link to status.

Comment: I'm using Redux to dispatch the API request so couldn't get my head around how I would set the status at the right point with that.. ended up using useEffect and https://formik.org/docs/api/useFormikContext#example

Comment: @SebastianThomas You can write your Redux thunk to return its Promise value (if it isn't already returning it), so that you can treat it like any other Promise and use `try`/`catch`, or `.then().catch()`, etc. For the OP's question, you'd use the `status` in the `catch` to communicate that there's an error.