# react native - how to display error authentication message on app screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, formik

I have a registration screen, in which when I fill out the input form with an existing details and submit, an error message 'the email has already been taken', I want the `message` that show in the `cmd` to display on my registration screen.

**registration.js screen**

```
    const handleSubmit = async ({ name, email, password } ) => {
        await axios.post(userRegister, 
            { 
                name, 
                email,
                password, 
            })
            .then((response) => { 
                console.log(response.data);
            })
            .catch(error => { 
                if (error.response) {
                    console.log(error.response.data);
                  }
            }); 
    }


<Formik
   initialValues={{ name: '', email: '', password: '' }}
   onSubmit={handleSubmit}
   validationSchema={validationSchema}
>
{ ({ handleChange, handleSubmit }) => (
   <>
            <View><Text>Show the error message here <Text/></View>
            {/* -------------- Form -------------- */}
            <View>
                <TextInput
                    onChangeText={handleChange("name")}
                    placeholder = 'Name'
                />

                ...... other form here
            </View>


            {/* -------------- Button -------------- */}
                <TouchableOpacity  onPress={ handleSubmit } >
                    <TextBold style={styles.fontColor}>Submit</TextBold>
                </TouchableOpacity>                         
   </> 
) }
</Formik>
```

Comment: Formik has a `status` object that's useful for storing API responses; things not specific to Form validation per se. [Formik `status` docs here](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#status-any).
I answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58049737/displaying-value-of-setfielderrors-using-errormessage-component-in-formik/58050411#58050411) a while ago that may be helpful.

Comment: I should add status to `{{ handleChange, handleSubmit, status  }}` and show it like this `<View><Text>{status }<Text/></View>` I will appreciate it if u help edit my code an new to it.